# How to add a Numpy Array to a dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

How to add two numpy arrays to a dictionary in python ?

```
a = [[1]
     [3]]

b = [array([[[ 41.,  179.],
             [ 451.,  254.],
             [ 449.,  10.],
             [ 53.,  256.]]], dtype=float32), array([[[ 181.,  313.],
             [  27.,  24.],
             [ 113.,  192.],
             [ 08.,  20.]]], dtype=float32)]
```

I wish to display a and b as

```
c = {1: array([[ 41.,  179.],
            [ 451.,  254.],
            [ 449.,  10.],
            [ 53.,  256.]], dtype=float32),
     3: array([[ 181.,  313.],
           [  27.,  24.],
           [ 113.,  192.],
           [ 08.,  20.]], dtype=float32)}
```

Comment: Does the solution have to be scalable?

Comment: Yes, it has to be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`c = dict(zip(a[:,0], b))` would turn your `a` and `b` variables into a dictionary. I'm not sure whether that's what you're looking for, though.

Comment: It returns an error saying -                                                     
    TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Comment: Oh right, I didn't notice the exact form of your `a`. I assume what you meant there was `a = np.array([[1],[3]])`. If that's the case, `dict(zip(a[:,0], b))` should do it.

Answer (score 2):

**Using a `dictionary comprehension`:**

I assume you meant to define `a` as:

```
a = [1, 3]
```

then you can get `c` with:

```
c = {e: b[i] for i, e in enumerate(a)}
```

which gives the intended output of:

```
{1: array([[[  41.,  179.],
    [ 451.,  254.],
    [ 449.,   10.],
    [  53.,  256.]]], dtype=float32),
 3: array([[[ 181.,  313.],
    [  27.,   24.],
    [ 113.,  192.],
    [   8.,   20.]]], dtype=float32)}
```

---

If you actually only have `a` as a `list` of an `element` as in `[[1], [3]]`, you can do:

```
a = [i[0] for i in a]
#[[1], [3]] --> [1, 3]
```

Comment: Still gives an error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'`

Comment: Am sorry, works perfect !! I made an error typing your code.

Answer (score 0):

small mistake in c, needs a comma between the two inner lists (are nested lists necessary here?)

Anyways, here is a solution that gives the desired output you want.

```
import numpy as np
c = {}

a = [[1],[3]]

b = [np.array([[[ 41.,  179.],
             [ 451.,  254.],
             [ 449.,  10.],
             [ 53.,  256.]]], dtype=np.float32), np.array([[[ 181.,  313.],
             [  27.,  24.],
             [ 113.,  192.],
             [ 08.,  20.]]], dtype=np.float32)]

for i in range(len(a)):
    c[a[i][0]] = b[i]
```

Create a dictionary first (c), then use the values in your nested list a as keys. for each of those keys assign the array in your list b at the same index (i). Do note that this requires that the indexes of a corresponds to the same positions in b.